# Adding prometheus as data source in grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-operator

I am adding Prometheus as a data source to the Grafana. I am getting  below error:

> Error reading Prometheus: bad_response: readObjectStart: expect { or
> n, but found #, error found in #1 byte of ...|# HELP pyth|..., bigger
> context ...|# HELP python_gc_objects_collected_total Objects co|..

I am using Python Prometheus client to generate the metrics. I am able to retrieve data from prometheus as below:

[image]

I am stuck here. Any kind of help is of great help.

Comment: It seems you are trying to add metrics page as a data source into Grafana. That's not how it works: Prometheus (server installed through [this guide](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/installation/)) scrapes metric from metric pages. And then Grafana uses said Prometheus server as data source.